# Join two lists returns IEnumerable in IEnumerable C# Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Im trying to join two lists, but the result gives me an IEnumerable in a IEnumerable when Im expecting only simple List. I can cast both IEnumerables to lists, but Im confused why this happens in the first place. Why is this and what do I need to do in order to get only one list from a join?

```
namespace arena.DAL
{

public class EquipmentData
{
    private Arena db = new Arena();

    public ArmorModel getArmor()
    {
        var user = UserData.getCurrentUser();

        var equipmentArmorList = db.EquipmentModels.Where(e => e.AccountId == user.Id && e.EquipmentType == (int)Constants.EquipmentConstants.EquipmentType.Armor).ToList();

        var armorList = db.ArmorModels.ToList();

        var result = from f in equipmentArmorList
                     join s in armorList
                     on f.EquipmentId equals s.Id into g
                     select g.ToList();
        return result;
    }

}
}


public class EquipmentModel
{
    public EquipmentModel()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentType { get; set; }
    public bool Equipped { get; set; }
}

public class ArmorModel
{
    public ArmorModel()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Biographi { get; set; }
    public double Health { get; set; }
    public double Stamina { get; set; }
    public double Strength { get; set; }
    public double Initiative { get; set; }
    public double Avoidance { get; set; }
    public double Armor { get; set; }
    public double Durability { get; set; }
    public int MinDamage { get; set; }
    public int MaxDamage { get; set; }
    public int ExperienceGain { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyGain { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public int Slot { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EF has IQueryables, not IEnumerables. You have to plain-old List<T> collections that you are trying to combine with LINQ to Objects. `ToList()` *executes* the query.

Comment: In any case, the code is wrong to begin with. ORMs deal with *entities* and *relations*. You should define relations and navigation properties in your entities and let the ORM do its job of generating the joins, *NOT* try to write joins in LINQ. If your `EquipmentArmor` entity had an `Armor` property, EF would load the related object automatically

Comment: Finally, `EquipmentArmor` sounds like a many-to-many relation table. That can be specified in the context's configuration too. Perhaps your `Equipment` entity should have an `ICollection<Armor>` property. PS: Enumerations can be mapped as well. No need to cast them to int

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had a feeling I was starting in the wrong end.. If I understand you correctly, I should do something similar to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Im puzzled tho how I should map my Equipment entity since the Equipment ID in combination with EquipmentType points to what entity it should link. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that it is unclear what you are asking for in `GetArmor`.

The return value says it should return exactly one ArmorModel. Yet your query results in a List which you try to return. Of course this won't compile.

Furthermore, even after your edit, the relationship between EquipmentModel and ArmorModel is unclear.

In your query, variable f has type `EquipmentModel` and s has type `ArmorModel`. You perform a join on the `EquipmentModel.EquipmentId == ArmorModel.Id`.

It seems that each `ArmorModel` has zero or more `EquipmentModels`. Or in database terms: there is a one-to-many relation between `ArmorModel` and `EquipmentModel`, where `EquipmentModel` has a foreign key to the primary key of the `ArmorModel` it belongs to in property `EquipmentId`.

Apart from the fairly confusing choice in property naming, this one-to-many relation is not modeled correctly in your classes. If you want Entity Framework to represent your one-to-many relation ship, the class definitions ought to be like:

[See this article about proper one-to-many Entity Framework relations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
class ArmorModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // an ArmorModel has many EquipmentModels
    public virtual ICollection>EquipmentModel> EquipmentModels {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class EquipmentModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // an EquipmentModel belongs to an ArmorModel via foreign key
    public int EquipmentId {get; set;}
    public virtual ArmorModel ArmorModel {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EquipmentModel> EquipmentModels {get; set;}
    public DbSet<ArmorModel> ArmorModels {get; set;}
}
```

Because of the mismatch between table names / foreign keys etc some Attributes or fluent API is needed. Consider changing the name of property EquipmentId to the proper defaults ArmoreModelId. Entity Framework will understand the one-to-many relationship automatically:

```
public class EquipmentModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // an EquipmentModel belongs to an ArmorModel via proper default foreign key
    public int ArmorModelId {get; set;}
    public virtual ArmorModel ArmorModel {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Now back to your question. Since there is such a big mismatch between your query and the type you should return, it is impossible to determine what you want.

If seems you want one special `ArmorModel` from the collection of all `ArmorModels`. It seems you want the one-and-only `ArmorModel` that has one or more `EquipmentModels` that match certain properties.

After the proper one-to-many definition your query would be much simpler:

```
var matchingArmoreModels = db.ArmorModels
    // I don't want all ArmorModels,
    // I only want those ArmorModels that have at least one EquipmentModel
    // that match certain conditions with AccountId and EquipmentType
    .Where(armorModel => armorModel.EquipmentModels
        .Where(equipmentModel => equipmentModel.AccountId == user.Id
            && equipmentModel.EquipmentType == ...)
        // it is enough if it has at least one matching EquipmentModel:
        .Any());
```

Now you have all `ArmorModels` that have at least one `EquipmentModel` with the correct `AccountId` and `EquipmentType`.

If and only if you are certain that there should be one element, you can return `Single`:

```
ArmorModel myOneAndOnlyArmorModel = matchingArmorModels.Single();
return myOneAndOnlyArmorModel;
```

If you think there might be no matching `ArmorModel`, use `SingleOrDefault`. If you think there might be several matching `ArmorModels` return either your complete sequence, or return the first matching one: `FirstOrDefault`.

Finally: it could be that an EquipmentModel does not belong to exactly one ArmorModel, but that it can belong to several ArmorModels. In that case the one-to-many relation is a [many-to-many relation, which is described here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

**Configure one-to-many in Fluent API**

If you use the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you don't have to explicitly define your one-to-many relations. Entity Framework will detect the automatically.

However if you want to use non-standard names for your foreign keys or for your navigation properties, like you do with the foreign key in EquipmentModel you'll have to help entity-framework.

The easiest to describe this in your override of `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

Every EquipmentModel belongs to exactly one ArmorModel, using foreign key EquipmentId. Every ArmorModel has many EquipmentModels in property EquipmentModels

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EquipmentModel>()
       .HasRequired(equipmentModel => equipmentModel.ArmorModel)
       .WithMany(armorModel => armorModel.EquipmentModels)
       .HasForeignKey(equipmentModel => equipmentModel.EquipmentId);
}
```

Alternatively you could configure the ArmorModel similarly: An ArmorModel has many EquipmentModelss. Every EquipmentModel belongs to exactly one ArmorModel, using foreign key EquipmentId.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ArmorModel>()
    .HasMany(armorModel => armorModel.EquipmentModels)
    .WithRequired(equipmentModel => equipmentModel.ArmorModel)
    .HasForeignKey(equipmentModel => EquipmentId);
```

Be sure not to specify both. After all: there is only one one-to-many relation

Comment: All your assumptions are correct and this is exactly what I was looking for. A Equipment can only have one "armor" since the character buys an equipment which links to what kind of armor, weapon or item it is.
Thank you so much for clearing it up!

Comment: Hi again @Harald, so sorry to ask but Im wondering if you could point me in the right direction. Your suggestion is correct, altho Im wondering if I should add one more virtual called for example: public virtual WeaponModel WeaponModel {get;set;} in order to be able to link towards a weaponmodel aswell. In that lies my dilemma of renaming EquipmentId to ArmorModelId.